# Testing Vue.js Filters

Tags: javascript, vue.js, testing, filter, jestjs

I am trying to write a test for my Vue.js filter, but I have no idea where to begin with filters in particular

**Filter**

```js
Vue.filter('pluralize', (word: string, amount: number) => amount > 1 ? `${word}s` : word);
```

**Usage in a Vue.js component**

```js
{{ 'recharge' | pluralize(count) }}
```

So if the count is is greater than 1, `Recharge` becomes `Recharges`.

**Test mark up**

This is as far as I've gotten thus far concerning the test mark up:

```js
import {createLocalVue} from '@vue/test-utils';

describe('pluralize', () => {
  let localVue = createLocalVue();
  localVue.filter('pluralize', (word: string, amount: number) => amount > 1 ? `${word}s` : word);

  it('returns plural suffix value', () => {
    // Test comes here...
  });
});
```

Comment: Have you checked if my answer works for you? @KD1

Comment: Hi @user9993 yes thank you it worked as suggested :)

Comment: Feel free to mark the accepted answer. @KD1

Answer (score 0):

If it's a filter then you can usually treat it as a [Pure function](https://www.sitepoint.com/functional-programming-pure-functions/). It always returns the same output for the given input.

Knowing this, I would instead test the function itself without trying to test it via a component. If it works by itself then you know it's going to work inside a component.

I'd also take advantage of ES modules, let's see how this will work.

`filters.js:`

```
const pluralize = (word: string, amount: number) => amount > 1 ? `${word}s` : word);

export {
    pluralize,
    // ... other filters
};
```

`filters.spec.js`:

```
import { pluralize } from './filters.spec.js';

describe('filters', () => {
    test('pluralize should return suffix value', () => {
        expect(pluralize('recharge', 10)).toBe('recharges');
    });
    // ... your other tests here
}
```

PS: This code isn't going to work if you try convert "cacti" to "cactus", you'd end up with "cactis".